# "turn off" required attribute in specified inputs when answering prior input

Tags: html

I'm hoping to turn off the form validation for a number of questions when a specific overarching question is answered. For example, questions 6-10 are no longer required if question 5 is answered as "no".

Snippet of HTML is below for context.

```
<ul class="ss-choices" role="group" aria-label="No Mobile Site  "><li class="ss-choice-item"><label><span class="ss-choice-item-control goog-inline-block">
<input type="checkbox" name="entry.1999905937" value="" id="group_1999905937_1" role="checkbox" class="ss-q-checkbox"></span>
```

```
<td class="ss-scalerow">
<div class="ss-scalerow-fieldcell">
<input type="radio" name="entry.131573405" value="1" id="group_131573405_1" role="radio" class="ss-q-radio" aria-label="1" required="" aria-required="true">
</div></td> 
<td class="ss-scalerow"><div class="ss-scalerow-fieldcell">
<input type="radio" name="entry.131573405" value="2" id="group_131573405_2" role="radio" class="ss-q-radio" aria-label="2" required="" aria-required="true"></div></td> <td class="ss-scalerow"><div class="ss-scalerow-fieldcell">
<input type="radio" name="entry.131573405" value="3" id="group_131573405_3" role="radio" class="ss-q-radio" aria-label="3" required="" aria-required="true"></div></td> <td class="ss-scalerow"><div class="ss-scalerow-fieldcell">
<input type="radio" name="entry.131573405" value="4" id="group_131573405_4" role="radio" class="ss-q-radio" aria-label="4" required="" aria-required="true"></div></td> <td class="ss-scalerow"><div class="ss-scalerow-fieldcell">
<input type="radio" name="entry.131573405" value="5" id="group_131573405_5" role="radio" class="ss-q-radio" aria-label="5" required="" aria-required="true"></div>
```

I want to be able to disable the required attribute for all the radio inputs if the checkbox input is selected.

Answer (score 2):

You would need to set and clear the required attribute when the checkbox is clicked

```
(function(document){
    var checkbox = document.getElementById('checkbox');
    var radio = document.getElementsByClassName('radio-buttons');

    var onCheckboxClick = function(){
        if(this.checked){
            radio.forEach(function(r){
                r.removeAttribute('required');
            });
        } else{
            radio.forEach(function(r){
                r.setAttribute('required', '');
            });
        }
    };

    checkbox.addEventListener('click', onCheckboxClick);
})(document);
```